# Date filter not working in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am not able to filter table results by date. Have tried all combinations(='2016-07-28', Date(2016-07-28)).etc. expiry column is set as "DATE" datatype[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing quotes around date

```
WHERE expiry = DATE("2016-07-28")
```

the reason it doesn't fail is because DATE(2016-07-28) is also legit it is equivalent to DATE(1980) which is in turn produces 1970-01-01 and this is why you have zero records returned. if you would have any records for 1970-01-01 you would get them

Comment: what data type of expiry? you can hover column name to see it

Comment: try running the same in Standard SQL mode. Make sure you change [  ] with \` \` (backticks)

Comment: I am using this Python API. Unrelated question - is there a better API for Python which gives standard SQL option as well? Cant see any option to set standard sql in this one. https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python

Comment: I think it is because of new data type - date that is introduced in BigQuery standard SQL . Will this be sufficient for you?

Comment: Yes. Will find out how to set the standard SQL flag in Python code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You should set uselegacysql attribute to false. This is part of configuration of job.insert API. I am on go now so don't have link handy. You should be able to find it